# Change font weight to bold for a drop down value in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have the following code in return. It is creating a drop down values. I want to change the font weight of the drop down value for ${status} and ${dataIdText} to bold

```
   <Modal.Body className="container-fluid">
  <div className='row'>
    <label className='col-sm-4' htmlFor='portalSelector'>Exiting item: </label>
    <select className='col-sm-8' id='portalSelector' onChange={this.onSelectionChange} value={this.state.selectedItem}>
      <option key='-1' label='--Make a selection--' value='-1' />
      {((dataId === '') ? stateVar : stateVar.filter((val)=> (val.dataId +"") === dataId )).map((p, index) => {
        const status = p.status === 'PENDING' ? '' : p.status === 'SENT'?'':'Unscheduled'
        const dataIdDef = datasets.filter((val)=> val.dataId === p.dataId )[0]

        const dataIdText = p.dataId === -1? '' : `${dataIdDef.dataIdname} - `

        const scheduleDtText = p.scheduleDt === 5711817600000 ? '' : 'scheduled for ' + moment(p.scheduleDt).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm')
        return (<option 
          className='data'
          key={index} 
          value={index}               
          label={`${status} ${dataIdText} ${p.title} ${scheduleDtText}`}>

        </option>)
      }
      )}
    </select>
  </div>
</Modal.Body>
```

I have tried to remove the label property and place the text inside Options tag itself but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

**Last Edit**

Turns out this may not be possible. The answer to "[How to style the option of an html "select" element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element)" back in 2011 pointed that out, and it appears that's still true.

Mozilla's `<option>` HTML element [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option), for example, say the only permitted content in the tag is "Text, possibly with escaped characters (like `&eacute;`)."

I won't remove the solutions I started off proposing, because they all seem like simple solutions to a simple problem, but it turns out it's not a simple problem at all (unless someone would care to correct me).

**End Last Edit**

**Initial answer**

Try passing the label a functional component rather than a string

```
return (<option
    className='data'
    key={index} 
    value={index}
    label={() => (
         <span><strong>{status} {datasetIdText}</strong> {p.title} {scheduleDtText}</span>
    )}
    </option>
)
```

**Edit in response to question update**

Is there a reason for you to need the string formatted in the "label" prop? It almost seems too obvious, so I apologize in advanced if you've already done this or it isn't an option, but why not just place the label in the `option` tag itself?

```
<option 
    className='data'
    key={index} 
    value={index} 
    // label={`${status} ${p.type} ${dataIdText}${scheduleDtText}`}
>
    {/* move label here */}
    <strong>{status} {dataIdText}</strong> {p.title} {scheduleDtText}
</option>
```

Comment: It is showing as [object object] in the drop down, not the proper value

Comment: My bad, that's not an unexpected error. I've updated my answer to address it, replacing the tag with a functional component. If that still doesn't work, please update your question to show how you're rendering the `label` prop.

Comment: It is not working. I have edited my question with the code details

Comment: Thanks for the additional detail, I've updated my answer again.

Comment: When I tried to move out the label in the option tag itself it is showing the following error "Only strings and numbers are supported as <option> children."

Answer (score 0):

try this shape

```
  label={()=>( <span className="bold">{status}<span className="bold"> {datasetIdText}<span/> {p.title} {scheduleDtText}`}>
```

Comment: When I am trying to pass a component it showing Invalid value for prop `label` on <option> tag. Either remove it from the element, or pass a string or number value to keep it in the DOM.